# Set notifications from iOS extension

Tags: ios, notifications, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions, ios-app-group

i've tried using

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

but it doesn't return anything. 
 An alternative would be to send a message to the main app so it can set a notification, but this would mean that my app has to be listening for a change in Userdefaults or a change in my AppGroup
Does anyone have any idea or advice?
thanks

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: That function isn't supposed to return anything. What is it that you're trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: @TomHarrington i'm trying to set a notification from an ios extension, but i'm not getting anything, not even an error from calling the function above.

Comment: I did it, i can set notification from the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could set a notification from my extension, the problem was that i was trying to do it from a function that is called using a timer. (so now the problem is my timer is not working in the extension)

 *** this is what is not working ***

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(loopInExtension), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 @objc func loopInExtension() {
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, nil)
}
```

So to set a notification i just had to add a notification, but not with a timer.

Comment: i succeed to set a timer and , i did this: 
            var timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { (Timer) in
                          // DO SOMEHING
                        os_log("I CAN SEE THIS")
            })
            RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)

Comment: But if i set a notification inside my timer i just get 1 notification and after i dismiss it, i receive again another one just when i close my extension. i don't get what it's happening... i'll do some more digging